# Extra space by polyglossia

Tags: luatex, polyglossia

The LuaLaTeX code...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\begin{document} 
English/\textgerman{German}
\end{document}
```

...results in an extra space after the slash. How can I avoid it?

Comment: I don't get a space. How old is your system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for caring. I use TexLive-2015 at OS X.

Comment: Then show the log-file.

Comment: It is 700 lines, quite long to paste here. This is a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7v1f7bj5bl5dgw/foo.log?dl=0

Comment: @Matthias pastebin would be better.

Comment: Your system is not really up-to-date. There is probably a spurious space in one of the gloss-files, but as in newer system it is gone, I can't help you to find it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You are right, `tlmgr update --all` solved the problem. If you give an official answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is not really up-to-date. There is probably a spurious space in one of the gloss-files, but in newer system it is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Because I currently use the version of TexLive found in cygwin, which is apparently not current enough, and don't have the `tlmgr` command available, I hunted down the spurious space.

It's in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-german.ldf`, in six different invocations of `\xpg@set@language@luatex@ii`, for example:

```
(line 225)        \xpg@set@language@luatex@ii{ngerman}
```

End these lines with `%` signs and the problem disappears.